# No OS in Harddrive

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot

I have a HP laptop 15-eq2040au model which has windows 10. Now started to install complete ubuntu in a 32gb pendrive. Now after doing all the process and starting the install i kept the laptop to do the process in the morning i saw the laptop is only booting ubuntu even when i am removing the pendrive it is ahowing there is no os in harddrive. What is happening and how to fix it ?

When i opened the bios setting there i check that the OS Setting is changed to UBUNTU (That is instead of windows it will alwas try to boot ubuntu by default). What to do now

Update: First i should say what the things i later noticed. In windows i had my device encryption on so i was not able to acess ssd in ubuntu. After some research online i ran `sudo update-grub` in linux terminal though it didn't work but somehow when i reatarted the pc and removed the bootable ubuntu usb it booted to windows. I dont know what exactly happened but it is now ok.

I will do the process of installing a full ubuntu in a usb again. So the errors may happen again. Please can you tell me any recovery actions i should take before hand before doing that  and also if the windows bootloader does get reset by linux how to revert it back to windows.

Comment: It seems like you Installed Ubuntu on Disk instead of pen drive. Can you explain what actually you did?

Comment: But i made sure that i selected pendrive for installing ubuntu